# How can I categorize objects by size?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, improvised-weaponry

I got two drunken masters in the party that fight with improvised weapons by melee and/or ranged. They have lots of teamwork related feats to aid each other and they make a very good mini team between them, with the rest of the party supporting their efforts. It works surprisingly well!

My problem as a DM is that we have to waste a lot of time determining the damage of the objects. A quick fix would be to seed the room with stuff we already decided the damage on but what I want is either a way to determine what size category an object is, without much effort, or a big list of things I can use as either a tie-breaker with my players, or to avoid arguments altogether.

Answer (score 4):

If the goal is to streamline your play session, I have this alternate suggestion for you:

A fighter doesn't pick up an item, then learn what size it is, and strike with it.  Instead, they know that this skill that is appropriate to use right now needs an item of XXX size, so they look around for one and pick it up.  So instead of "I pick up a chair.  Is this large or medium?" - have your players say "I pick up the nearest medium object" - and you can follow up with "You grab a stool from the nearest table."  Or sometimes "There's nothing of that size to hand".  It doesn't even matter if today you let him pick up a stool for a medium object, and next week as a large one, if any of your players even notice and question this, stools aren't always the same size anyway.

TL;DR: your fighters are experts in improvising weapons, they would know what they were picking up better than the players or even the GM does, so just let them get what they need.

Answer (score 1):

### When in doubt, create a table

If you're having issues determining the damage of items that may or may not be in the area, grab a list of furnishings that you might fill an inn with and divide those objects up by size rating ( small, medium, large, huge ).

Once you have this table created, divide the objects up and assign them damage values, then assign each object a die number on a d20 or a d40(2d20, with a 2-40 range) and when they say they want to grab an object, roll on the table for size.

```
d6   Size of objects   Base damage
1 Tiny                   1d2
2 Small                  1d3
3 Medium                 1d4
4 Large                  1d8
5 Huge                   2d6
6 Gargantuan             2d8

d20  List of objects   Damage
1     Chair (S/M)       ----
2     Stool (S/M)       ----
3     Glass Mug (T/S)   ----
4     Barrel (M/L)      ----
5     Keg (M/L)         ----
```

Of course you'd have to fill in the chart yourself, but you get the idea. Populate the tables, divide the items up by size, and create base damage for each size category and individual item that you feel fits your purposes.